# Find $x$ for $2 \arcsin x = \arccos 2x$.

Tags: trigonometry

I have to solve the equation:

$$2 \arcsin x = \arccos 2x$$

I see that we have the following conditions:

$$\hspace{6cm} x \in [-1, 1] \hspace{5cm} (1)$$

from the left-hand side and

$$2x \in [-1, 1]$$

$$\hspace{6cm} x \in \bigg [-\dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2} \bigg ] \hspace{5cm} (2)$$

from the right-hand side. Combining $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have that:

$$x \in \bigg [ - \dfrac{1}{2}, \dfrac{1}{2} \bigg ]$$

But I don't know how to solve the equation itself. I tried something like this:

$$\sin (2 \arcsin x) = \sin (\arccos 2x)$$

And something like this:

$$\cos(2 \arcsin x) = \cos (\arccos 2x)$$

$$\cos (2 \arcsin x) = 2x$$

But either way, I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this:
$$\begin{align}
\sin(2\arcsin x)&=\sin(\arccos 2x)\\
2\sin(\arcsin x)\cos(\arcsin x)&=\sqrt{1-(2x)^2}\\
2x\sqrt{1-x^2}&=\sqrt{1-4x^2}\\
4x^2\left(1-x^2\right)&=1-4x^2\\
0&=4x^4-8x^2+1\\
0&=(2x^2-2x-1)(2x^2+2x-1)
\end{align}$$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes, I can take it from there but I do not understand is why is it that $\cos (\arcsin x) = \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ and that $\sin (\arccos 2x) = \sqrt{1 - (2x)^2}$. Can you please explain how you got those two formulas?

Comment: OK, the real answer is that these are just some of those facts that you end up memorizing, like the quadratic formula. But for an explanation, consider a right triangle drawn in the usual orientation with hypotenuse $1$ and height $x$. $\arcsin(x)$ is the angle opposite $x$. Then cosine of that angle is the length of the base. But by the Pythagorean theorem, that base's length is $\sqrt{1-x^2}$. So $\cos(\arcsin x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ in general.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos (2t)=1-2(\sin t)^{2}$. So $\cos (2\arcsin x)=2x$ is same as $1-2x^{2}=2x$. Solve this quadratic to find $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cos(\arcsin(x))=\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)$ in general, therefore $$\cos(2\arcsin(x))=\left(\cos(\arcsin(x))\right)^2-\left(\sin(\arcsin(x)\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2-x^2$$

Thus $$\cos(2 \arcsin x) = \cos (\arccos 2x)\iff\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2-x^2=2x$$

Comment: Where did you find those formulas that apply in general? I never saw them before and am very confused.

Answer (score 0):

Using https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Principal_values

we need $$-\pi\le2\arcsin x\le\pi$$

and $$0\le\arccos2x\le\pi$$

$$\implies2\arcsin x\ge0\implies x\ge0$$

Now set $\arcsin x=y$ to find $$2(\sin y)=\cos(2y)=1-2\sin^2y$$ which is on rearrangement a quadratic equation in $x=\sin y$

Remember $x\not<0$

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in identifying the domain $x \in [ - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} ]$. Next, let $\theta = \arcsin x$, or, $\cos^2\theta =1-x^2$. Then, continue with your last equation

$$\cos (2 \arcsin x) = \cos2\theta = 2\cos^2\theta -1=1-2x^2 = 2x$$

for which the only valid solution in the domain $[ - \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} ]$ is $\frac{\sqrt3-1}2$.